# Unknow cause for list index out of range error

Tags: python, index-error

'''
I have a small part of my program causing me problems as I am running through test cases.  I have a check to make sure the user inputs three values. If the user doesn't enter three values, it displays a message and then calls the function again.  If the user enters three values the first time, it makes and prints the calculation and continues on. This is where it gets wonky, if the user doesn't input three values, it prompts the user again until they enter three values, then it makes and prints the calculation and THEN gives me the out of index error.  I have a print statement in there to check the input list and there are three values there... I'm completely at a loss for why I get the error on the second pass but not the first.
'''

```
def cos_angle():
    get_data = input("Please enter the known two sides and the angle\n" +
                     "across from the unknown side.\n" +
                     "(Entries should be separated by a space) ").split()

    if len(get_data) != 3:
        print("\nIncorrect number of entries.  You should input three numbers.\n")
        cos_angle()

    side_a = int(get_data[0])
    side_b = int(get_data[1])
    angle = int(get_data[2])
    print(get_data)
    c = sqrt((side_a**2 + side_b**2) - 2*side_a*side_b*cos(rad(angle)))
    print("\nThe value of the missing side of the triangle is {:.4f}.\n".format(c))

cos_angle()
```

Comment: Use a loop, not recursion. There are multiple `get_data` variables with different values.

Comment: Or return after making the recursive call.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple `get_data` variables with different values.

Use a loop, not recursion.

```
def cos_angle():
    get_data = input("Please enter the known two sides and the angle\n" +
                     "across from the unknown side.\n" +
                     "(Entries should be separated by a space) ").split()

    while len(get_data) != 3:
        print("\nIncorrect number of entries.  You should input three numbers.\n")
        get_data = input("Please enter the known two sides and the angle\n" +
                         "across from the unknown side.\n" +
                         "(Entries should be separated by a space) ").split()

    side_a = int(get_data[0])
    side_b = int(get_data[1])
    angle = int(get_data[2])
    print(get_data)
    c = sqrt((side_a**2 + side_b**2) - 2*side_a*side_b*cos(rad(angle)))
    print("\nThe value of the missing side of the triangle is {:.4f}.\n".format(c))

cos_angle()
```

Comment: So this worked beautifully.  Thank you.  
I am seeing the same problem in another part of my program that uses recursion (I'm just now discovering it).  I will definitely look into do a loop here as well, but I am just curious, WHY is this happening?  I've been using python a couple years, off and on, self-taught... but now I am majoring in computer science and I'm really interested in finding out the whys.

Comment: @Stretch333 Each recursion call creates a new variable `get_data`, reads user input and splits the input into 3 values. But only the last call contains a variable with valid input data. Use your debugger to see what's going on.

Comment: thank you so much for explaining.  I will definitely look into this further.  I can certainly see why recursion can be very tricky.